# Can a derived type be the same name as a nested type of its base?

Tags: c++

Is the following code legal?  MSVC 9 and g++ 4.4 disagree:

```
struct base
{
  struct derived {};
};

struct derived : base {};

int main()
{
  typedef derived::derived type;
  return 0;
}
```

MSVC complains, confusing the nested name for the type's constructor:

```
c:\dev>cl test.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
test.cpp(10) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'
test.cpp(10) : error C2761: '{ctor}' : member function redeclaration not allowed

test.cpp(10) : error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier
```

While g++ does not:

```
$ g++ --version test.cpp
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

For context, my code contains an iterator called `pointer`. To provide the iterator interface, it provides the nested type `pointer`, which is a synonym for itself.

Comment: I believe that ```typename``` is illegal in non-templated code, or at least some compilers complain about it.

Comment: Try it with `typedef typename derived::derived type;` and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. By the way, for Comeau your code is illegal (with and without `typename`), so I'm inclined to think that VC++ is right here.

Comment: FWIW `gcc 4.6.2` doesn't accept the code as well and gives a very descriptive error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) thinks that your code is incorrect, so I think that the constructor-interpretation shadowing the type-interpretation is what the standard mandates<sup>1</sup>.

Still, your code happily compiles if you clear up the ambiguity and tell the compiler that you're trying to access the `derived` member of the base class:

```
struct base
{
  struct derived {};
};

struct derived : base {};

int main()
{
  typedef derived::base::derived type;
  return 0;
}
```

By the way, the fact that the constructor-interpretation prevails kinda makes sense: you have a well-known way to tell the compiler that you want to refer to stuff of the base class (via the scope resolution operator), but you wouldn't have a syntax to do the reverse (forcing the compiler to understand that you're referring to the constructor). So the "constructor-by-default" behavior seems quite sensible.

---

1. I may look it up later, but I don't guarantee that I actually will, this kind of pesky name issues are always a mess to look up.

Comment: Thanks!  ```std::iterator_traits``` chokes on it, unfortunately.  I will have to specialize it I guess.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have a pointer wrapper, ```pointer<T>```, which derives from ```boost::iterator_adaptor```. The pointer wrapper encodes metadata in the type system.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a coflict in the names.
Just rename the second struct  to struct `derived2`.
And do this change in `main()` too: `typedef derived2::derived type;`
It compiles without errors in VC++6.0

```
struct base
{
  struct derived {};
};

struct derived2 : base {};


int main()
{
  typedef derived2::derived type;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't check some code for standard conformance with VC++6.0... :S